# Visual studio without license

Tags: visual-studio, licensing

What version of visual studio without license i can use to creat a website and upload it to the internet without breaking any rules?
and also is it counts as commercial use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All versions of Visual Studio have a licence - that's not the same as them costing money.

You can use [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products) for free and still create commercial websites though.